# position_dodge and nudge_y together

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am trying to add labels (letters) above a barplot using ggplot2 function `geom_text`. My bars are separated using `position=position_dodge()` and so I need to apply the same for the new labels. However I would like to use also `nudge_y` to separate the labels from the bar. If I try to use both together R complains that I can use only one of either options. I'd like to do something like this:

```
Tukey.labels <- geom_text(data=stats,
                    aes(x=factor(Treatment2), y=x.mean, 
                        label=Tukey.dif),
                    size=4, nudge_y=3,            # move letters in Y
                    position=position_dodge(0.5)) # move letters in X
```

To create something like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pc8Y.png) Does anybody knows a possibility to shift all my labels the same distance in Y while doing `position_dodge` at the same time? I could not find answer for this in other posts

Comment: Have you tried `vjust`?

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't change the letter based on the size of the bars

Answer (score 7):

Hard to troubleshoot without a reproducible example. Hopefully this helps:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("car") , 
       aes(as.factor(cyl), mpg, group = car)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mpg - wt,
                    ymax = mpg + wt),
                position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = gear, y = mpg + wt), vjust = -0.5,
            position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it's perfect. It didn't work before because I was giving vjust positive value.

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of the original question, one can easily combine ggplot's `position_nudge` and `position_dodge` like this:

```
position_nudgedodge <- function(x = 0, y = 0, width = 0.75) {
    ggproto(NULL, PositionNudgedodge,
        x = x,
        y = y,
        width = width
    )
}

PositionNudgedodge <- ggproto("PositionNudgedodge", PositionDodge,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    width = 0.3,

    setup_params = function(self, data) {
        l <- ggproto_parent(PositionDodge,self)$setup_params(data)
        append(l, list(x = self$x, y = self$y))
    },

    compute_layer = function(self, data, params, layout) {
        d <- ggproto_parent(PositionNudge,self)$compute_layer(data,params,layout)
        d <- ggproto_parent(PositionDodge,self)$compute_layer(d,params,layout)
        d
    }
)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Tukey.labels <- geom_text(data=stats,
    aes(x=factor(Treatment2), y=x.mean, label=Tukey.dif),
    size=4,
    position=position_nudgedodge(y=3,width=0.5)
)
```